# Reusing Product.xml and Package.xml from Bootstrapper packages

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.7, prerequisites

The Visual Studio Setup and Deployment uses Prerequisites. 
These Prerequisites come as Bootstrapper packages with preconfigured Product.xml and Package.xml.

Can I reuse these configuration XML or do I need to redo the configuration when I making a `PackageGroup` for WiX?

The SQLExpress2008R2 Bootstrapper package:

- product.xml: Contains related products and calls a SQLExpressCheck.exe
- package.xml: Decides on the Architecture and has default arguments for installing the SQL Server

If I cannot reuse the Product.xml and Package.xml in Burn, should I resort to the BootstrapperFile in the WixProj file?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you have to create your own PackageGroups and ExePackages. While some information can be copied from the Visual Studio Bootstrapper packages, you should look for the installation documentation for the prerequisite. Sometimes the real installation instructions are hidden in the release notes or even MSDN blogs. You might have to Google for "silent" or "unattended".

---

It wouldn't do any good to add `GenerateBootstrapper` to the .wixproj file because .wixproj files are not designed to import the common microsoft targets.

Comment: GenerateBootstrapper actually works in this case creating a setup.exe which is a bootstrapper for the prerequisites added used the item "BootstrapperFile"

Answer (score -1):

I decided in my case to instead of writing Burn PackageGroups use the following setup in the wixproj.

I have 7 Bootstrapper Packages with complex product.xml and package.xml and it would have made no sense to recreate Burn Package Groups.

```
    <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperFile Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0">
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 und x64)</ProductName>
    </BootstrapperFile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
  <WindowsSDKBootstrapperPath>$(registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\4.0@Path)</WindowsSDKBootstrapperPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <GenerateBootstrapper ApplicationFile="$(TargetFileName)" ApplicationName="Rodenstock Consulting" ApplicationRequiresElevation="True" BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" ComponentsLocation="Relative" CopyComponents="True" OutputPath="$(OutputPath)" Path="$(WindowsSDKBootstrapperPath)" />
  </Target>
```